# Proper way to connect joist to top plate?

Tags: framing, construction

What's the proper way to connect an element like this:

[image]

I was thinking [hurricane ties](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Z-MAX-Galvanized-18-Gauge-Hurricane-Tie-H2-5AZ/100275721) but was wondering if there was a better connector.

Comment: In your SketchUp model, your corner column should support your plate. Can't toenail a top plate into the vertical face of a column in any case.

Comment: Can we get an updated picture w/ final solution?

Comment: The double plates should turn sideways as this is essentially an edge beam. It will then allow the joist directly attached to it through the side (vertical) face.

Comment: Context is critical here. Wall sheathing often serves as a shear connection. Ties are required in some cases. Voting to close as vague.

Comment: @isherwood better late than never I guess

Answer (score 2):

The answer ultimately depends upon your local climate/weather (heavy wind loading?), but generally the way to handle that situation is to span the joists at the top plate with a "rim joist", then toenail all the joists to the top plate.

BTW... you might want your top plate to extend over the top of that corner post instead of nailing to its side.

Comment: For an occasional carpenter, framing anchors (aka "hurricane clips") may provide significantly more satisfactory results than attempted toenailing because the nails tend to be smaller (e.g. those 10d x 1 1/2" Simpson sells versus a normal 10d or 16d).

Comment: True, especially in places where - for example - the flooring has already been laid on top of those joists so there's no room left for a hammer or air nailer. A rattlegun could still get into the pocket, but framing anchors (provided you can get those cool stubby nails) can simplify things somewhat. Around these parts, nobody seems to carry those cool stubby little nails, though.

Comment: The big box home improvement retailers and Amazon carry them.

Comment: The B.O.B. is an hour away. Amazon's a good source, though - I never thought to look for 'em there. I've just been hoarding 'em when I find 'em. 8)

Comment: I was under the (false?) presumption that some sort of tie would be superior than toenailing. Plus like @benrudgers mentioned, I am an occasional carpenter, so anything that makes the process easier (even if a bit more expensive) and equally as good, I am all for.

Comment: Also the top plate corner post connection is not like that, I just got a lil lazy in SketchUp, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Toe nailing does not give any value. Only nails in shear...like those used in clips.

If you don’t want to use clips, you can provide a rim joist and attach sheathing to the rim joists and the building. (Don’t forget to anchor the posts down too.)

Answer (score 0):

Most US building codes require forces to be calculated in accordance with *ASCE-7: Minimum Design Loads for Buildings and Other Structures*. Some may offer prescriptive design requirements, these tend not to include proprietary engineered products such as specific Simpson Anchors.

The Simpson H2.5A can make framing easier. However, it may or may not be suitable for the specific application. Because it is an Engineered product, proper Engineering analysis of the structure is necessary. From the [H2.5A Product page](http://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/H.asp#):

> Considerations for Hurricane Tie Selection
>
> 1. What is the uplift load?
> 2. What is the parallel-to-plate load?
> 3. What is the perpendicular-to-plate load?
> 4. What is the species of wood used for the rafter and the top plates (Select the load table based on the lowest performing species of wood.)
> 5. Will the hurricane tie be nailed into both top plates or the upper top plate only?
> 6. What load or loads will the hurricane tie be taking?*
> 7. Select hurricane tie based on performance, application, installed cost and ease of installation.
>
> ---
>
> - When a connector is loaded simultaneously in more than one direction,    the allowable load must be evaluated as shown here. For all connectors, use the following equation:
>
> Design Uplift/Allowable Uplift + Design Lateral Parallel to Plate /
> Allowable Lateral Parallel to Plate + Design Lateral Perpendicular to
> Plate / Allowable Lateral Perpendicular to Plate < 1.0.
>
> The three terms in the unity equation are due to possible directions
> that exist to generate force on a hurricane tie. The actual number of
> terms used in the equation for each condition is dependent on
> designer’s method of calculating wind forces and the utilization of
> the tie in the structural system.
>
> As an alternate, certain roof to wall connectors (embedded truss
> anchors, seismic and hurricane ties (on this page), and twist straps)
> can be evaluated using the following: The design load in each
> direction shall not exceed the published allowable load in that
> direction multiplied by 0.75.